# Set default controller but not to affect other controller and paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to replace root to welcome controller,

But if I use the url `http://localhost:3000/welcome/portfolio` The action 'welcome' could not be found for WelcomeController

How to not affect original controller with the routes rule `match '/:action(/:id)', :controller =>  "welcome",via: [:get, :post]`

### rake up routes

```
                 Prefix Verb     URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
                   root GET      /                            welcome#index
                        GET|POST /:action(/:id)(.:format)     welcome#:action
portfolio_welcome_index GET      /welcome/portfolio(.:format) welcome#portfolio
          welcome_index GET      /welcome(.:format)           welcome#index
                        POST     /welcome(.:format)           welcome#create
            new_welcome GET      /welcome/new(.:format)       welcome#new
           edit_welcome GET      /welcome/:id/edit(.:format)  welcome#edit
                welcome GET      /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#show
                        PATCH    /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#update
                        PUT      /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#update
                        DELETE   /welcome/:id(.:format)       welcome#destroy
```

### route.rb

```
  root :to => "welcome#index"
  match '/:action(/:id)', :controller =>  "welcome",via: [:get, :post]
  resources :welcome do
    collection do
      get 'portfolio'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

it happens because `/:action(/:id)` handel each path with format `/something/some_id` and even `/something` so you could put it to the end in routes file:

```
 resources :welcome do
    collection do
      get 'portfolio'
    end
  end

  match '/:action(/:id)', :controller =>  "welcome",via: [:get, :post]
  root :to => "welcome#index"
```

in this case request to `/welcome/portfolio` will be handled with `resources` definition before going to your `/:action(/:id)` definition.

Comment: Please note the call to `root` at the *end* of the file

Comment: @RichPeck, it doesn't matter, because it just match root '/' path. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root